# What's the minimum safe immersion time to sanitize something with StarSan?

Tags: sanitation, sanitizer

How long should I keep something immersed in StarSan/swish it around for to ensure that it's as sanitized as I could reasonably hope it'll be?

I know everyone has a rule of thumb for this (I use 1min myself), but I was wondering if there are any hard numbers (culture tests or contamination rates etc) for this. How long does StarSan take to effectively sanitize something (clean plastic or metal)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Charlie Talley from StarSan has said that 30 second contact time is 99+% effective. That is based on tests that they've done.  Immersion isn't necessary.  I keep StarSan in a spray bottle and just spray things down, wait 30 seconds, and use them.

Comment: Here's a link to the show. http://thebrewingnetwork.com/shows/The-Sunday-Session/The-Sunday-Session-03-19-06-Sanitation-w/-Charlie-Talley

Comment: Exactly.  There is no rule of thumb, its the directions for the product.